# Migrating OS and some games to new SSD while kepping everything else on old HDD

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, migration

Basically what I want to do is to migrate my OS (Windows 8.1 Home) and a game to my new Samsung 960 EVO M.2 SSD to make them boot and load faster. But I still want to keep all my other programs and documents etc. on my old HDD. Is it even possible to run this configuration?
Would it be possible if I back up my current HDD to another hard drive and then delete as much as possible except the OS and that game from it, then migrate it to the new SSD using Samsung's migration tool and then move over all the backup files that I want to my now empty HDD. Would this work or is there any other way that would?

I'm such a noob at storage and I'm sorry if my explanation is confusing, It's my first time posting a question like this. Any answers is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you keep asking (and deleting) the same question? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is you use Clonezilla which you can download it in clonezilla.org and burn it in DVD or also in USB as bootable by using Rufus.

Basically clonezilla copies your entire old HDD drive (files & OS) included to your new SSD or you can chose to copy the OS partition only depending on your partition. You should be aware that SSD size should be greater than the HDD or partition size that you're copying from.

If you find clonezilla is too much complicated you can also find some other alternatives for it with much simpler options but beware some of it may cost you real money.

Comment: Clonezilla has also option for beginner use that may help you to use it easlily. At least I hope it will fix your demand.